# Please explain algebra for conditional probability $ Pr(C|B) = ... 1Pr(A|B) + 0(Pr(A^C | B)) $

Tags: probability

Blitzstein, *Introduction to Probability* (2019 2 edn), Chapter 2, Exercise 22, p 87.

> 22. A bag contains one marble which is either green or blue, with equal probabilities. A
>     green marble is put in the bag (so there are 2 marbles now), and then a random marble
>     is taken out. The marble taken out is green. What is the probability that the remaining
>     marble is also green?
>
> ### Solution:
>
> Let A be the event that the initial marble is green, B be the event that the
> removed marble is green, and C be the event that the remaining marble is green. We
> need to find $P(C \mid B)$. There are several ways to find this; one natural way is to condition
> on whether the initial marble is green:
>
> $ P(C|B) = P(C|B \cap  A)P(A|B) + P(C|B \cap A^C)P(A^C|B) = 1P(A|B) + 0(P(A^C | B)) $

I am having trouble seeing how an author reached the RHS of this conditional probability expression, particularly where the $0, 1$ coefficients came from.  Could someone please explain the algebra?

Comment: Lewis Carroll did have a problem, that would probably have landed him in jail nowadays. But you must be thinking of *another* problem. It would be useful to make it clear what it is.

Comment: @AndréNicolas I don't think there is any conclusive (or any) evidence that Lewis Caroll had that problem (if it's the one I think you're talking about).

Comment: A picture is worth a thousand words. In his case, there were *lots* of pictures.

Comment: @T. Webster, this certainly isn't right in general. For instance, by taking $A$ any event with 0 probability this would give us that every conditional probability $P(C|B)=0$. The middle of the equality is true, but the RHS you ask about only holds if $B$ and $A^C$ are mutually exclusive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$P(C \mid (A \cap B))$ is the conditional probability that the remaining marble is green, given that the original marble was green and a green marble was drawn. It should, I hope, be obvious that $P(C \mid (A \cap B)) = 1$.

$P(C \mid (A^c \cap B))$ is the conditional probability that the remaining marble is green, given that the original marble was blue and a green marble was drawn. It should, I hope, be obvious that $P(C \mid (A^c \cap B)) = 0$.

So the rightmost expression is obtained by substituting these values in the expression in the middle. It might have been better to use $\times$ or $\cdot$ between the numbers and $P$ and thus avoid the possibility of confusion.

Answer (score 1):

This problem is used in Professor Blitzsteins' course *Statistics 110* which is available from iTunes U. It is stated in *Strategic Practice and Homework 2 problem 3.1*. The first equality wasn't immediately clear to me so here are the details:

By the definition of conditional probability we have that
$$
 P(X \mid Y) = \frac{P(X \cap Y)}{P(Y)}
$$

so to restate this in terms of the problem we have that
$$
 P(C \mid B) = \frac{P(C \cap B)}{P(B)}
$$

Now we want to find $P(C \cap B)$.
By the definition of the probability function we have that the probability of the union of disjoint events are the summation of the probability of each event. If we have an event $Z$, we can decompose that into two disjoint events like this
$$
 P(Z) = P((Z \cap A) \cup (Z \cap A^c)) = P(Z \cap A) + P(Z \cap A^c)
$$

Notice that one can also use the law of total probability to get the above result since one can always partition a sample space $S$ into $A$ and $A^c$ given $A \subseteq S$.

Let $Z = C \cap B$. This leads to
$$
 P(C \cap B) = P((C \cap B \cap A) \cup (C \cap B \cap A^c)) = P(C \cap B \cap A) + P(C \cap B \cap A^c)
$$

By using the definition of conditional probability once on each term in the above we get
$$
 P(C \cap B) = P(C  \mid  (B \cap A)) P(A \cap B) + P(C  \mid  (B \cap A^c)) P(A^c \cap B) 
$$

Using the definition of conditional probability again on the second factor of each term we get
$$
 P(C \cap B) = P(C \mid (B \cap A)) P(A \mid B) P(B) + P(C  \mid  (B \cap A^c)) P(A^c \mid B) P(B)
$$

resulting in
\begin{align}
 P(C \mid B) &= \frac{P(C \cap B)}{P(B)} \\
        &= \frac{P(C \mid (B \cap A)) P(A \mid B) P(B) + P(C  \mid  (B \cap A^c)) P(A^c \mid B) P(B)}{P(B)} \\
        &= P(C \mid (B \cap A)) P(A \mid B) + P(C  \mid  (B \cap A^c)) P(A^c \mid B)
\end{align}

Comment: How does this help the OP with regards to where the '0' and '1' come from?

Comment: I think that has already been answered very well by Dilip Sarwate. For me the difficulty was the first part and since others might have the same difficulty I thought I would include the answer for completeness along with where the problem comes from in case another Google search ends up here.